# Algorithm to join two AVL trees together in O(logn) time

Tags: algorithm, tree, avl-tree

So I'm trying to figure out an algorithm to join 2 AVL trees together in O(logn) time, where n is the total number of integers in both trees and is also odd. In this problem, the integers in the trees are distinct from one another. Additionally, each node of the trees store the size of the subtree rooted at it. I was thinking of adding the elements of the smaller tree into the larger one but I wasn't sure how to go about proving that this would take O(logn) time. Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I could go about this?

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible.

**Proof**: Assume you had an algorithm to join 2 AVL search trees in `O(logn)`, and let it be `A(T1,T2)`

We now represent a new sorting algorithm: `Sort(A)`<sup>(1)</sup>

```
Sort(A):
  Let T_i be an AVL tree consisting only of A_i  // O(1) n times, total O(n).
  curr_size = 1
  while curr_size < size(A):
    Let T_i, T_j be two trees of size curr_size  // O(1)
    // Assume without loss of generality i < j.
    if there are such T_i,T_j:
      T_i = A(T_i,T_j)  // O(log(curr_size))
    else:
      curr_size = curr_size * 2  // O(1)
  return in_order(T_0)  // O(n) by in-order traversal.
```

The algorithm complexity is:

```
T(n) = n/2 * log(2) + n/4 * log(4) + n/8 * log(8) + ... + 2*log(n/2) + log(n)
```

Explanation

First we need to merge all trees of size 1 to trees of size 2. This requires n/2 merges, each takes O(log(2)). Next, merge the resulting n/2 trees to trees of size 4. This is done n/4, each O(log4), ... lastly we have two trees and we merge them once, and it takes O(n).

This gives us the formula:

```
T(n) = sum (n/2^i * log(2^i)) for i=1,2,3,...,logn
```

We could do some more algebra, but I take a shortcut and feed it to [Wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum%20%28%28n%2F2%5Ei%29*log_2%282%5Ei%29%29%20%20i%20from%201%20to%20log_2%28n%29), which gives us:

```
T(n) = 2n -log(n) -2
```

Since the above is linear, this means our general purpose sorting algorithm Sort(A) is linear.

But Sorting is `Omega(nlogn)`.

This means something is wrong - so the assumption that such an algorithm `A(T1,T2)` exists, with `O(logn)` complexity is wrong.

**QED**

---

<sub>(1) For simplicity, the algorithm assumes size`(A) = 2^i` for some `i` in `N`. This restriction can be relaxed without changing the conclusion, only changing the complication of the algorithm.</sub>